# Is there a way to open the "Session and Startup" GUI from terminal?

Tags: command-line, xfce

I am new to Linux in general so forgive me if my question is unclear.

While attempting to install the i3 desktop and window manager, I accidentally configured my desktop such that the "Activities" bar is no longer shown. I will need to access "Session and Startup" in order to undo my mistake. Is there a way to open the "Session and Startup" GUI, usually located in Activities -> Settings, without the Activities menu?

Thanks! Below, is additional information about the circumstances surrounding the problem. It may or may not be relevant.

I am running Xfce4 in a Crosh environment on an Acer Chromebook using Crouton. To install i3 I was following the instructions found here, but restarted Xfce4 prematurely: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/i3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bring up a terminal, then run:

```
xfce4-session-settings
```

If you want to know what application command, navigate to `/usr/share/applications`, then right click on the application's icon to select "Properties" in the context menu.